Problem with conditional CSS media query for mobile phones
I am trying to have two columns in landscape mode or one column in portrait or landscape mode on phones.
For some reason I am getting one column on my iPad Pro when in portrait mode. Can anyone help me understand why?
Tested on the largest iPad Pro and an iPhone 12 mini, both machines in both orientations. The iPhone is correct, one column in portrait, two in landscape. The iPad is two columns in landscape (correct), but one column in portrait (incorrect).
This is my CSS:
article {
    max-width: 99%;
    columns: 2;
    }

@media only screen
      and (min-width: 375px)
      and (orientation: portrait)
    {
    article {
        columns: 1;
        }
    }


You wrote:

For some reason I am getting one column on my iPad Pro when in portrait mode. Can anyone help me understand why?

Your media query is as follows:
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  article {
    columns: 1;
  }
}

Any iPad Pro, regardless of the model, will definitely be wider than 375px, no matter if in portrait or in landscape mode (the model I am aware of has a 1024x1366px screen).
So your media query will apply to any iPad Pro in portrait mode, and therefore you get the one column you see!
To get two columns, I would simply change that media query to something like this:
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  article {
    columns: 1;
  }
}

This will create one column on all mobile phones in portrait mode and on all tablets in portrait mode  which are less than 600px wide when held in portrait mode. Note that I used a max-width value, which means "smaller than" / "less than"...
You can change that value according to your needs, for example to 768px if you also want it to apply to older iPad models and iPad mini.

It's possible to use the newer range syntax - in your example that would be (width <= 600px) - in place of the 'traditional' (max-width: 600px) approach, the newer version requiring less of an explanation. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#targeting_media_features

Well, in your situation, it's possible that the screen of the iPad Pro is too large and your CSS code didn't take this into consideration. Your media query, which is the min width: 375px, may be too small for an iPad. The screen width of an iPad is much wider than 375px, so your media query may not be effective.
You can try increasing the min width a bit, such as changing it to min width: 1024px, which should trigger it on the iPad. Alternatively, you could simply remove the min width and make all vertical mode devices display only one column.
However, I have to say that I am not 100% sure because I have not tried it on your devices. You can try it and see how it works. If it doesn't work, it may need to be adjusted again.
@media only screen
      and (max-width: 1024px)
      and (orientation: portrait)
    {
    article {
        columns: 1;
    }
}

That's it, I hope it's helpful to you.

My suggestion:
    article {
      max-width: 99%;
      columns: 2;
    }

/* This media query targets devices with a maximum width of 1024px 
in portrait mode */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
      article {
        columns: 1;
      }
    }

/* This media query targets devices with a maximum width of 768px 
in portrait mode */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
      article {
        columns: 1;
      }
    }

/* This media query targets devices with a maximum width of 375px 
in portrait mode (i.e. most phones) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) and (orientation: portrait) {
      article {
        columns: 1;
      }
    }

